# snowpipe in different schema and tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

do snowpipe works with different schema and tables.

example, i created snowpipe in schema xyz , but my table is in different schema .
do snowpipe works like that?

Also can one snowpipe works for different file which has different columns.

please help!

Answer (score 1):

> Does Snowpipe work with different schema and tables?

Snowpipe is an automation system to run COPY statements. There is no requirement to create the Snowpipe in the same schema as the table. So you can create a Snowpipe in schema XYZ but your target table can be in a different schema.

> Also can one Snowpipe work for different files which has different
> columns?

This is related to COPY INTO command and your source file. If you use one of the following file formats, you can use the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME, so your COPY command can be used for different files with different columns.

- JSON
- Avro
- ORC
- Parquet

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions